# Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency app.0001_initial on database 'default'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make custom made user model for my project in `Django`.

My **models.py**:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Inspector = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Industry = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Industry(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='industry_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    license = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    industry_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)


class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='employee_releted_user')
    industry = models.OneToOneField(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee_releted_industry')
    i_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    employee_varified = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Inspector(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='inspector_releted_user')
    inspector_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)


class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='admin_releted_user')
    admin_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

in **settings.py**:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.myCustomeUser'
```

Here `admin.site.register` is also done in `admin.py`. Now it shows the following message in the terminal while I try to `migrate` or `makemigrations`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line   
    utility.execute()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle       
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 295, in check_consistent_history        
    raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency app.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

What does it mean? And I also don't want to set the default value of `username` & `password` in this `myCustomeUser` model. And also please suggest me that, is this a correct way to make `usermodel`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project

Comment: Here I also try to `migrate` after dropping my full database, but it doesn't work. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You will have to  delete and remake migrations, just migrating again would not solve issue as it is documented

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating from django user model to a custom user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794212/migrating-from-django-user-model-to-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: @iklinac I have just run `python manage.py migrate admin zero`,
`python manage.py migrate auth zero`,
`python manage.py migrate contenttypes zero`,
`python manage.py migrate sessions zero` to delete my migrations and then re `makemigrations` and `migrate`, but still that problem stay.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error will usually happen if you've done your first initial migration without including your custom user model migration file. Exactly as the message says:

> "admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency custom_user_app_label.0001_initial on database 'default'"

Since beginners will always do their initial migration and then create a custom user afterward. In the first migration, it will migrate all built-in Django apps including `admin`. Now with the custom user model, Django wanted it to be the first initial migration to be executed.

See Django docs [Changing to a custom user model mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project:%7E:text=Due%20to%20limitations%20of%20Django%E2%80%99s%20dynamic%20dependency%20feature%20for%20swappable%20models%2C%20the%20model%20referenced%20by%20AUTH_USER_MODEL%20must%20be%20created%20in%20the%20first%20migration%20of%20its%20app%20(usually%20called%200001_initial)%3B%20otherwise%2C%20you%E2%80%99ll%20have%20dependency%20issues).

> Due to limitations of Django’s dynamic dependency feature for swappable models, the model referenced by AUTH_USER_MODEL must be created in the first migration of its app (usually called 0001_initial); otherwise, you’ll have dependency issues.

---

In my case, I have Django v4.1 installed.

This is how I reproduce the issue:

- I had initially migrated my application previously. Then
- Created a custom `User`.
- Added the app into `INSTALLED_APPS`.
- Created migration files `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to the new custom `User` by `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp_label.User'`
- Got the migration error issue as the OP.

This is how I resolve the issue:

- Drop the database but **DO NOT** delete the `User` initial migration.
- Make sure in your `0001_initial.py` -> class `Migration.initial` is set to `True`.
- Run migration `python manage.py migrate`
- Your `User` initial migration should be the first migration file in the order of migration execution. See this migration output as example:

  ```
  Running migrations:
   Applying myapp_label.0001_initial... OK
   Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
   Applying admin.0001_initial...
  ```

As you can see it was executed first followed by the contenttypes then the admin.

Answer (score 5):

1. Comment  `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` in project `urls.py` file.
2. Then in `settings.py` file comment `django.contrib.admin` in installed app.
3. Do `makemigrations` and migrate it new table with your customize fields for user is created in table.
4. You can uncomment out above after the migration, it will work too.

Working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, but I just deleted my migrations from every app, and drop the database, and created a new one. And use `

> `python manage.py makemigrations`
> `python manage.py migrate`

to make new migrations and everything is working as it should be.

Comment: Dropping database is not a solution in most casess