# Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key

Tags: python, django

I am working with a custom build user model in **Django** and there was some message in the terminal at the time of `migrate` given in the [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65562875/migration-admin-0001-initial-is-applied-before-its-dependency-app-0001-initial-o).

However, I have failed to solve that and it didn't hamper to run the project, so I actually ignore it and continue with my code. Now when I try to log-in to the `admin panel`(http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/) it shows the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 407, in login
    return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 92, in form_valid
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 131, in login
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 20, in update_last_login
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 847, in _save_table
    raise ValueError("Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.")
ValueError: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue,I searched everywhere.
I found the answer in the link I will attach below.

1-to change the database name.
2-makemigrations and migrate.

but it failed to work until I read towen's comment! I was always creating
the super user before
migrating, **which is wrong!**

> **you have make the migrations before creating the super user.**
> so

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

then all the tables are ready to work properly, now we can create the super user, and it will have the primary key and it will work

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/3