# Django zappa error: InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on

Tags: django, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, zappa, python-zappa

So, I'm using Zappa on AWS Lambda.  I just added a custom user model to my project and tried to migrate to the RDS on AWS and Zappa gives me the following error:

```
InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

Now, I know that if I got this error on my local server, I would do this:

```
python manage.py migrate admin zero
python manage.py migrate auth zero
python manage.py migrate contenttypes zero
python manage.py migrate sessions zero
```

I would then run the migrations to destroy their tables and recreate them again (see [this helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44171779/3549766))

However, if I ran

```
zappa manage dev migrate
```

after that, I get

```
InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database
```

How should I do the same thing on the AWS RDS using Zappa or should I do something else?

Comment: if you're going to destroy and rebuild your tables, why not destroy and rebuild your migration files?

Answer (score 0):

I simple destroyed the table using the [zappa-django-utils command](https://github.com/Miserlou/zappa-django-utils/tree/master/zappa_django_utils/management/commands):

```
zappa manage prod drop_pg_db
zappa manage prod create_pg_db
```

The tricky part was to create a new admin user.  Since I replaced the auth model with the accounts model, I had to use the raw python command:

```
zappa invoke --raw dev "from django.accounts.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('admin@yourdomain.com', 'ohsosecretepass')"
```

Typically, the custom user model should be implemented before any migrations as many things are related to the User model.  So, dropping all the tables were inevitable though I tried to avoid it.