# im trying to write a custom user model and when i try to migrate i keep getting this error :

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, backend, web-development-server

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 295, in check_consistent_history
    raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency Occupier.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating from django user model to a custom user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794212/migrating-from-django-user-model-to-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: hi thanks for answering , although i have read the recommended article before and still got the same error