# IntegrityError at /admin/api/user/6/change/ FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django

I am developing a website on django. When I am trying to delete a user via admin panel i get an error. I can change e.g. staff status (while still getting an error, but changes are getting apllied) The code is below:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):

    emailSpam = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    email = models.EmailField('email', unique=True)

    first_name = None
    last_name = None

    confirmedEmail = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["emailSpam"]
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import User


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import User


class Admin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = User
    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)


admin.site.register(User, Admin)
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Perhaps you have *another* model with a field like, `field = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE...` that is causing the problem.  When you try to delete the user all objects of *this* field have to be deleted.

Comment: Problem is that i don't have such models XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible solutions**
There are three things that *might* be causing the issue, at least as far as I can tell.  The first you already discounted.  I hope it's the second solution, since that will be easier, but I fear it might be the third, which would be hardest to get around.

**Cause One**
As my comment stated, perhaps there is *another* model with a field that has `User` as a `ForeignKey` with `on_delete = models.CASCADE`.  When you try to delete the `User`, all instances of this class that has that `ForeignKey` will need to be deleted as well (because of `on_delete=models.CASCADE`), and that's what's causing the issue.  You have already stated you have no such models, so let's move on to solution 2.

**Cause Two**
I hope it's this one, since it might be easier to fix.  I noticed you have `email = models.EmailField('email', unique=True)` as one of your fields for your User model, but `AbstractUser` should already have an `email` field.  Try removing that field, makemigrations and migrate, and see if the issue is resolved.

**Cause Three**
Did you [change from the default `User` model to the custom user you are now using in mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project)?  In other words, did you, in this project, *ever* run `makemigrations` **before** you switched to a custom user model?  That can be a big problem.  However, there are two solutions for this, not so easy or desirable, but doable.

*Solution A:*  If this is a new project with no valuable data yet, you can simpy delete your database, delete all migrations in all folders, as well as all `__pycache__` folders as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53599345/10951070).  Then re do `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.  Of course this will **erase** all your tables, so you wouldn't want to do this mid-project.

*Solution B:*  There is a way to handle this mid-project *without* losing data. The steps are out in this django [ticket 25313](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313), or [these](https://rasulkireev.com/custom-user-model-mid-project-django/), more readable instructions.